# Create Hidden Association Columns in a Workflow

Tags: workflow, hidden, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013 to create a SharePoint 2010 document set approval workflow for a  SharePoint 2016 site and was wondering how I can go about setting the association columns to be hidden?

I don't want the created associated columns to show up on my Welcome Page input form of the Document Set, but I need them to be associated with the document library for the workflow.

Comment: You can make the columns as "Hidden" from content type settings. and you can still use those columns in your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to make your column hidden from Forms:

1. Go to Library settings.
2. Select you document set content type from **Content types** section(if not visible then enable it from **Advanced settings** by selecting Yes in **Allow management of content types?** option).
3. In Content type setting, click on the column name which you want to hide from the forms.
4. Select **Hidden (Will not appear in forms)** option from Column settings section.

It will hide those columns from all the forms. But, you can still use those columns in your workflow.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of how to make them hidden for columns created for the Document Set Content Type, but when I create Association Columns in my workflow that are created when the workflow runs in the case of one of the dropdown options, I do not see the ability to hide the columns created by the workflow itself, only the columns that initially created for the document set.

Comment: Are using reusable workflow??

> you can associate your reusable workflow to a specific content type.

How you have associated your document set content type with you reusable workflow?